# Rails - what would be the correct relations between models here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a bit puzzled and looking for some advice

I have an app with Users, each **User** has a **Company** and each company has **Transactions** going on.

```
Company
has_many :transactions

Transaction
belongs_to :company
```

But now I am in the need of including **Categories** for better organization  and management of the user transactions. I want the user to create Categories himself, and after that add new Transactions to the category he created directly. So kind of like Transaction now belongs_to a category. That being said I don't feel like breaking my current model, because it works as I want it too and just feels right (the company performs transactions).

My routes are already nested enough, so making another layer will uglify my situation even more. This

```
  resources :users do
    resources :companies, shallow: true do
      resources :transactions, shallow: true
    end
  end
```

Into

```
  resources :users do
    resources :companies, shallow: true do
      resources :categories, shallow: true do      
        resources :transactions, shallow: true
    end
  end
end
```

Any advice here? Maybe someone had similar dilemma? Should I establish multiple belongs_to on the Transaction model, or should I restructure? What would be the optimal routing in my situation? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know the exact details of your implementation I can't give the best advise possible, but what I can do is tell you how I'd structure these relations based on my understanding of the relationships that you're trying to model:

```
Company
has_many :categories
has_many :transactions, through: :categories

Category
belongs_to :company
has_many :transactions

Transaction
belongs_to :category
```

You could route this in several ways. Also, if a user can only access the companies which they own then you don't need to include /user as part of the route, instead you can just get the user_id in your controller separately.

```
/[user]/[company]/[category]/[transaction]
/[user]/[company]/[transaction]
```

Please note that I haven't tested this, if you have issues with it let me know and I'll spin up a sandbox and make sure that it works.

Comment: Does this mean my Transaction model has to have two foreign keys?

Comment: Nope, the transaction model only has one FK: `category_id`. By using `has_many :transactions, through: :categories` in your Company model, Rails will automatically traverse through your categories in order to get all the related transactions for your company.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't confuse fleshing out your domain modelling – in this case, adding the `Category` model – from structuring your routes file. It's not compulsory to have controllers for every model in your domain.

In this case, it sounds like you want to adjust your model to something like:

```
def Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
  has_many :transactions, through: :categories
end

def Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :transactions
end

def Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

What you don't get 'out of the box' from the above model is a direct association from the transaction to the company – belongs_to doesn't have a :through option. However, calling `.category.company` on the transaction will get you to the correct model, and you can wrap that into an instance method within `Transaction` if needed.

You can, of course, retain your company_id attribute within your Transaction model and retain the `belongs_to :company` call. That gives you the upside of a direct link between each transaction and the company that made it. But it places an extra onus on you to maintain the relationships correctly. Ultimately, it's up to you which approach to take, depending on your business requirements.

When it comes to resources and routes, you shouldn't need to nest too deeply – especially as for any given transaction there will be only one category, and one company. Personally, I might opt for the following nesting (any shallow options omitted):

```
resources :companies do
  resources :categories
  resources :transactions
end
```

Ultimately again, concentrate on delivering straightforward forms to your users, and that'll tend to point towards straightforward approaches to routing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Company
has_many :transactions

Category
has_many :transactions

Transaction
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :company

Add resources :categories out side.
```